# Unexpected result for solving ordinary linear differential equation of second order with SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I am trying to solve this ordinary linear differential equation of second order [image: \ddot{s}+k^2s = 0] with SymPy and get an unexpected result.

```
import sympy as sym
k, t = sym.symbols('k, t') 
s = sym.Function('s')

diff_eq = sym.Eq(s(t).diff(t, 2) + s(t) * k**2, 0) # everything fine here, when I print this I get what I expected.

solution_diff_eq = sym.dsolve(diff_eq, s(t))  
print(solution_diff_eq)
```

Which prints

```
Eq(s(t), C1*exp(-I*k*t) + C2*exp(I*k*t))
```

However, the [solution I expected](http://shrani.si/?25/4E/2EBlVFVC/capture.jpg) is [image: s = A \sin{kt} + B \cos{kt}]

Any ideas what I have done wrong?

Comment: When I substitute the answer into the original equation and ".doit()" it checks out as a solution. Is it possible that it represents a valid alternate-form of the other solution (which I am not able to see from here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result prints as

```
Eq(s(t), C1*exp(-I*k*t) + C2*exp(I*k*t))
```

which is correct, as `I` is the imaginary unit. You might prefer the real form, but sympy was not notified of that and produced the most simple form as sum of exponential terms, especially as it is not clear if `k` is actually real.

If you make it explicit that `k` is a positive real number via

```
k = sym.Symbol('k', real=True, positive=True)
```

the solution is actually in real form, as you were expecting

```
Eq(s(t), C1*sin(k*t) + C2*cos(k*t))
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer! :)