# Using scipy solve_ivp for equation with initial conditions

Tags: python, scipy, equation, differential-equations

I am having a hard time getting used to scipy's solve_ivp. So let's say we have an ordinary linear differential equation of second order, spring for example (y'' = -k**2*y). Conditions are when the spring is at position 0 (time 0) speed is v0. How can I use initial conditions to solve it?

```
y'' = -k**2*y  # First this needs to be modified into first order equation
```

.

```
def function1(t, y, k):  #original function
return y[1], -k**2*y[1]

function2 = lambda t, y: function1(t, y, k = 10)  #function with only t and y

t = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000)

solution = solve_ivp(function2, (0, 100), (0, 0), t_eval = t)

solution.y[0]
```

Comment: You are aware that the spring at rest will remain in rest without external influences? Is this code a direct copy of the one you tried? If not, please compare for any differences. What exactly is your problem with the result of this code?

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, just gave it as an example...Let me rephrase the problem. a = -k^2 * s . I am trying to solve this kind of differential equations. If you take into account initial conditions, the solution for velocity for example should be: v = v0*cos(k*t). I am not sure how to archive this using solve_ivp.

Comment: You will need to look into `sympy` and its (imperfect) `dsolve` if you want symbolic solutions in python. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/53971293/3088138 or the sympy documentation.

Comment: I would like to get numerical result, not with symbols.

Comment: Then how do you want "the solution for velocity ... should be: v = v0*cos(k*t)." to be understood? What, apart from the index error in the ODE function, is the problem?

Comment: I get some form of "result" with the code above. But when I plot it, it doesn't look like a sin or cos function as it should. I assume this is since I don't know how to correctly comply with initial conditions and consequently get the wrong output.

Comment: Your ODE as encoded should get solutions `x0+v0/k^2*[1-exp(-k^2*t)]`, I think your plot reflects that exponential function.

Comment: ok, so not what I was hoping for. How should I change my code so that the solution would be the same as I mentioned earlier (v = v0*cos(k*t) ) or s = v0*sin(k*t) / k.  I can then additionally add k = 50 for example and v0 = 80. So I will get numerical output...

Comment: See below, just correct the one index. It is not really a problem with your solve_ivp use.

Comment: Thanks you for you help! When I insert numbers as initial conditions it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to encode

```
y'' = -k**2*y
```

as a first-order system, you should use

```
def function1(t, y, k):  #original function
    return y[1], -k**2*y[0]
```

The code in the question encodes `y''  = -k**2*y'`.

Comment: @John: You also need to alter your `solve_ivp` call to something like: `solve_ivp(function2, (0, 100), (v0, 0),  t_eval = t)`. This sets the initial condition to `y(0) = v0`, and `y'(0)=0`. The original code uses `(0,0)` for the 3rd argument, which implies `v0 = 0`, which reduces `v0*cos(kt)` to a flat line.

Comment: @unutbu Thanks! I understand. But how can I modify it forward, since in this case I get an error since v0 has not been defined...It is used the first time now.

Comment: When I insert directly numbers, it works! Thank you!